# java.lang.NullPointerException- error in Android

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I'm creating a simple login activity using phone number and password for my android application. I want to pass the user entered a phone number to my welcome screen, but the problem is I'm getting the above error when the user didn't log out the first time and then after running the application. Please help me to solve this error.

this is my LoginActivity.java file,

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputphone_number;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputphone_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String phone_number = inputphone_number.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(phone_number, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                     

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                        // this is how i sent phone number to next activity
                        dashboard.putExtra("phone_number", phone_number);


                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

this is MainActivity.java file,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



       /**
     * Dashboard Screen for the application
     * */        
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        TextView phone_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userNameView);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        String phoneNumber = i.getExtras().getString("phone_number");
        phone_number.setText(phoneNumber);

        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }
//  setContentView(R.layout.main);

//  MainDBAdapter mainDBAdapter = new MainDBAdapter(this);
    DatabaseHandler mainDBHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);


}

public void onClickedJobs(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TourNumberList.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
 }
```

UserFunctions.java file,

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param phone_number
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String phone_number, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_number", phone_number));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param phone_number
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String phone_number, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_number", phone_number));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}

}
```

This is LogCat error,

```
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tourinfo/com.example.tourinfo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.example.tourinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-08 10:27:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Network Operations should not be execute on Main Thread.

Comment: what is the line number 37?

Comment: have you declared mainactivity in yourmanifest..?

Comment: this is line 37- String phoneNumber = i.getExtras().getString("phone_number");

Comment: loginactivity not passing phonenumber properly..

Comment: you can simply pass the values as bundle it will be easy for u. or u can go for `sharedPreferences`

Comment: in the first time it working without any problem.but when user didn't logout and close the application, and after running project get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in line 37 replace

```
i.getExtras().getString("phone_number");
```

with

```
i.getStringExtra("phone_number");
```

use sharedpreferrence :-
For saving

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("text1",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        if (phone!= null) {
            editor.putString("phone", phone);
        }
editor.commit();
```

for fetching back :-

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("text1",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        phone= sharedPref.getString("phone", null);
```

Comment: but in the first time, enter the phone number and password in loginActivity it passing phone number without any problem. when user didn't logout and after trying to run app this error occurred.

Comment: use sharedpreference to store the phone number and fetch from it every time

Comment: how can i use sharedpreferences to this, i have no idea how to use it.

Comment: it shows error underline in context, where context.getSharedPreferences.

Comment: u can use ActivityName.this.getSHaredPreferences in place of context